# Telerik ASP.NET AJAX: How to get value of a data bound column, client-side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, telerik

I want to obtain the value of a hidden control, that is a `TreeListBoundColumn` of a TreeList:

```
<telerik:RadTreeList ID="rtlRshItems" ...>
    <Columns>
        <telerik:TreeListBoundColumn DataField="FtcPrevious" 
            UniqueName="FtcPrevious" Visible="false" runat="server">  
        </telerik:TreeListBoundColumn>
    </Columns>
</telerik:RadTreeList>
```

This is what I have coded but does not work (although it comes from Telerik's forums)

```
// Calculate the new FTC
var treeList = $find("<%= rtlRshItems.ClientID %>");
var ftcPrevious = treeList.get_items().getItem(0).findControl("FtcPrevious");

var ftcPreviousValue = ftcPrevious.value;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would probably be easier to utilize `ClientDataKeyNames` and `get_dataKeyValue()` instead of trying to hide a column.

Change the definition of the RadTreeList control to something like:

```
<telerik:RadTreeList ID="rtlRshItems" ClientDataKeyNames="FtcPrevious" ...>
    <Columns>
    </Columns>
</telerik:RadTreeList>
```

Adjust your Javascript:

```
var treeList = $find("<%= rtlRshItems.ClientID %>");
var ftcPreviousValue = treeList.getItem(0).get_dataKeyValue("FtcPrevious");
```

*Note: The most recent [Telerik documentation for RadTreeList](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/treelist-class-members.html) does not list `get_items()` as a valid function call. Adjust as needed for your version.*

Comment: Why isn't the `get_dataKeyValue()` property not shown in the Telerik documentation?

Comment: It is. You have to look under `TreeListDataItem` to find it. The `getItem()` function returns a `TreeListDataItem` object, but the documentation does not state this. http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/treelist-dataitem-class-members.html The Telerik Javascript (what they call client-side) documentation is very hard to follow in general and doesn't usually have very good examples.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would recommend setting the **Display="false"** attribute on the telerik:TreeListBoundColumn  element rather than Visible="false". I believe this may be the culprit.

Second, have you tried using getColumnByUniqueName() client-side function:

```
var treeList = $find("<%= rtlRshItems.ClientID %>");
var ftcPrevious = treeList.getColumnByUniqueName("FtcPrevious");
```