# RadTreeList with RadContextMenu (how do I get the Primary Key and ParentID of the selected node?)

Tags: asp.net, webforms, telerik, radtreelist

I am using a RadTreeList control to display a bunch of items. I added a RadContextMenu to the page and set the OnItemClick event so I can use it in the code behind to set the URL of my RadWindow based on Insert and Edit. Then I open a radwindow using that url.

It looks exactly like the one in [this demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/controls/examples/integration/treelistwithcontextmenu/defaultcs.aspx?product=treelist)

```
    protected void rcMenu_ItemClick(object sender, RadMenuEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Item.Value)
        {
            case "Insert":
                url = "~/Admin/ManageItemsDialog.aspx?ID="
                break;
            case "Edit":
                url = "~/Admin/ManageItemsDialog.aspx?ID="
                break;
        }
}
```

In here I am trying to retrieve the ID and the ParentID of the selected item from the tree list. The ultimate goal is to open a RadWindow passing the ID and ParentID through the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **SelectedItems** property of the TreeList control. Open the RadWindow as shown here: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-troubleshooting-opening-from-server.html. Its **GetDataKeyValue** method will give you the needed values

Also, consider doing this on the client only: [Telerik ASP.NET AJAX: How to get value of a data bound column, client-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9523733/telerik-asp-net-ajax-how-to-get-value-of-a-data-bound-column-client-side). The **get_selectedItems()** will give you the needed items http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/treelist-client-side-basics.html

Comment: Thank you so much for getting me thinking on this one. I completely forgot I can just access my RadTreeListControl right in my rcMenu_ItemClick function and just do object ItemID=RadTreeList1.SelectedItems[0]. I am so used to doing complex things that I didn't realize it was right in front of me all along. Thanks again!!